# Word/phrase/etc. to refer to that one action of constantly pointing out other people’s mistake/(so-called) flaws to their face

Tags: word-choice, word-phrases

I’m looking for a word/phrase/etc. to refer to that action/activity of constantly pointing out certain mistake/(so-called) flaw to the person having that flaw/doing the mentioned mistake.

For example, I’m fat and I feel perfectly fine with being fat. But somehow my friend constantly tell me “Look at you, so fat” or “How about dieting?” or “You eat a lot, no wonder you’re fat.”

Or I can’t use computer and I don’t mind not being able to operate it but my co-worker constantly tells me “You can’t use a computer” or “How sad, you don’t know how to use a computer.” and it happens every time we meet.

Like they constantly slap the fact that I’m fat/I can’t use a computer to my face. However, I don’t think “to slap sth. to someone’s face” is the one I’m looking for.

Edit: I think I’ve found it: “to rub something in someone’s face.” But please correct me if you think it’s not the one.

Comment: What does the idiom “Rub (Something) in Someone’s Face” mean?

Definition:

Humiliate someone by repeating and criticizing his or her mistake

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/516799/191178

Comment: Sounds a little like _shaming_ .

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

**touch a raw nerve**

> If you say that you have touched a nerve or touched a raw nerve, you mean that you have accidentally upset someone by talking about something that they feel strongly about or are very sensitive about.

*The mere mention of John had touched a very raw nerve indeed.*

[Collins]

Comment: Yes, but the OP  doesn’t apparently care about being fat or not being able to use a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the expression:

***[Find fault with:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-find-fault-with)***

> If you find fault with something or someone, you look for mistakes and complain about them.

> - I was disappointed whenever the cook found fault with my work.

(Collins Dictionary)